# JQuery Drop Down List select option by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, selenium

I have a select statement and a bunch of options. How do I choose an option by text using jQuery and at the same time deselect the default one, I am using selenium webdriver with python but I want to be able to do this in jQuery, because it seems like a basic thing I should know in jQuery and I would be able to translate it to python selenium myself once I understand how the jQuery works.

```
<select id="DropDownList">
  <option selected="selected" value="2"> Test1</option> 
  <option value="8"> Test2 </option> 
</select>
```

This is close to what I want. I have tried multiple functions and selections, but they result in either an empty array, or when I loop them give me all a list of undefined, or a list of every possible attribute they can have. The site is also designed using jQuery mobile if that makes any big difference in selection. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean select by text? This should work:

```
$("#DropDownList option:contains(" + 'Test2' + ")").attr('selected', true);
```

Update: to deselect previously selected value, you can do:

```
$("#DropDownList :selected").attr('selected', false);
```

Comment: I tried something similar and gave me an empty array. Why do you do plus signs before and after Test2?

Comment: whoops! haha i had a mistype in my id, but still curious about the plus signs are, do you have to add Test2 to the stringed command or something?

Comment: @KyleCalica-St Oh, that was just in case you wanted to put a variable there instead of a string, there is no need for them for just the Test2 string  ;)

Comment: sweet thanks a bunch! I never knew of that contains method before its amazing!

Comment: Works as in changing the attribute, but doesn't affect the page and doesn't get rid of the default value, i'll add that to the question.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St updated answer, add that line before the other one and it should deselect the Test1 option

Comment: Yeah that would normally work found out why now. There's a backend script that changes the company and everything, so I just had to execute the .load(url, SwitchOption() ) command, where Switchoption() was a function written by another developer. Everything else worked however.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St oh yeah those are always hard to find. Glad you got it to work though